# Lucene : Pagination returning duplicates

Tags: java, search, indexing, pagination, lucene

I am working on implementing pagination in Lucene. Currently I have implemented it with TopDocs and I am getting duplicate results back a lot of time. What am I doing wrong? Here index is the page-number which I am starting with 1 and incrementing by 1 after every search and resultSize is number of objects requested.

Code :

```
 Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
  IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
  IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
  Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("contents", "*" + text + "*"));
  TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(9999);
  indexSearcher.search(query, collector);
  TopDocs topDocs = collector.topDocs(index-1, resultSize);
          for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
               Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
               IndexableField value = document.getField("score");
          }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First parameter is the start index, not page. You need to multiply it by per page:

`TopDocs topDocs = collector.topDocs((index-1) * perPage, resultSize);`

See https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocsCollector.html#topDocs-int-int-